# the "hero" component of iris not installed when using "dep" to manage project dependencies

Tags: go, dep, go-iris

this question also posted here: https://github.com/kataras/iris/issues/1081

I am using "iris" as the MVC framework in my golang project, and i use "dep" to manage the dependencies of my project.

the "iris" dependency was configured in "Gopkg.toml" as bellow:

[image]

[image]

and later i use "dep ensure -v" to download all the dependencies.

after the "ensure" command finished, i check the downloaded files in "vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/hero" folder, i found there is no source code files were downloaded, refer to the screen capture bellow:

[image]

so i cannot use "hero" component in my project, because the "hero" related package not installed in my project.

[image]

thanks all for your help ~

Comment: Just to confirm. This is in the `$GOPATH`? Right?

Comment: @HamzaAnis yes, it's in my $GOPATH. All other "iris" components were installed successfully, except the "hero" component.

Comment: Do not use iris.

Comment: @Volker thanks, i did some study about go mvc frameworks, and understand why you do not recommend iris. but currently the other frameworks cant fulfill my requirements, for example, the gin framework dont support i18n , etc.

Comment: @Ace.Yin Did you run `dep ensure` before using the `hero` package in your code? `dep` removes sub-packages that are not used, so if you didn't have code written that used `hero`, `dep` would have thought it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to Go; but I had a similar issue with another library 'https://github.com/jedib0t/go-pretty'

```
$ dep ensure -add github.com/jedib0t/go-pretty
"github.com/jedib0t/go-pretty" is not imported by your project, and has been temporarily added to Gopkg.lock and vendor/.
If you run "dep ensure" again before actually importing it, it will disappear from Gopkg.lock and vendor/.
```

The repo is cloned into `pkg/dep/sources/https---github.com-jedib0t-go--pretty/` however there is no Go code in `vendor/github.com/jedib0t/go-pretty/`

I added an import `"github.com/jedib0t/go-pretty"` into one of my source code files and ran `dep ensure -v` however the vendor copy does not have any Go code it it. I removed the folder and tried again however same result.

What solved it for me was specifically importing the package I wanted into my code eg: `"github.com/jedib0t/go-pretty/table"` and running `dep ensure -v` again. I'm not sure why it worked but maybe my experience can help you or someone else.